# Range indicators in Angular or Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am developing an Angular application where I want to represent proximity of a value to the either side of the range. This is very similar to the Yahoo Finance indicator as shown in the image below.

How can I achieve that in Angular or Bootstrap?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview

Comment: I can define min value and max value to it but can't display them on either ends like the screenshot above

Comment: You would have to add those on your own. Not difficult to place a couple of labels on a page